# Trying to save photo taken by camera, but app crashes

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to use the built in camera app to take a picture and save it.  It works fine if it just takes a p[icture. When I add the copde to save the pictures, the camera app crashes when I exit from it
code

```
takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);       
try {
    File f  = new File(getFilesDir(), "test");
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));   
} catch (Exception e) {
    gi++;
}
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

Comment: Post the logcat please

Comment: I Suggest You Use The Instruction in Below Link To work with Camera API :

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Comment: instead of Uri.fromFile(f) try Uri.parse(f.getPath())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing camera:

```
@Override
      protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
    }
}
```